# Audio op am for low noise high volume

Tags: transistors, operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, speakers

I am trying to make a high quality circuit to take mp3 (stereo) signal and drive a 4 ohm speaker. I have been using the LM368 as in the picture below and this has ok quality when the volume is low but the noise and bass are terrible when you turn the volume up at all.Do I need to bypass the 5V better with a big electro? Should I consider a BTL amp?

[image]

Can anyone recommend a way to improve the sound quality or increase the volume? If not, does anyone know a better audio opamp that might suit my needs (there are so many I don't know where to start)

Thanks,

Comment: Delete Q1 for a start, or at least add a base resistor. It will clamp the output.

Comment: LM386 won't drive 4 ohms well (and it's not an opamp). There are lots of better power amps from the LM380 onwards. Also, Q1 will clip the positive peaks adding even more distortion. Insert a 1k resistor in series with its base.

Comment: Sorry that was an old schematic. I have taken Q1 out and it has improved slightly. @BrianDrummond -- So you would recommend the LM380? I am limited with providing 5V source and somewhat limited on overall space of the circuit but I guess I'm really looking for the best audio amplifier I can get to improve the quality

Comment: Hi, Mitch. I see you still have [Q1's base connected directly to the speaker](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214044/leds-flash-with-music). You can't expect a lot of power from a 5 V supply. Once the output gets close to zero or +5 V the signal will square off or 'be clipped'. You could look at putting in a second amplifier and running the speaker in 'bridged mode' but really you need a higher voltage. Alternatively you could build a more efficient cabinet - a horn design, for example, would give a much higher sound level than a simple box.

Comment: Did you learn absolutely nothing about that transistor (Q1) in the previous question you asked: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/214044/leds-flash-with-music

Comment: Great, so you just added a formerly unstated requirement. I would NOT recommend the LM380 at 5V. You'll have to look for something that can drive both ends of the speaker in "bridge mode" (and that means each stage must be able to drive 2 ohms. )  Armed with that info, check the usual sources. Oh and there's NO WAY 5V will ever light 4 LEDs in series.

Comment: A 4ohm speaker requires ove 1A of current to drive properly at 5V, and that's with no "damping" (more damping=better sound reproduction). You may want to use a FET to current-buffer your output for such a current-hungry load.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the 4 LEDs in series were addressed in his prev. question...just an old diagram there.

Comment: Thanks all. I will make sure I upload my newest schematic next time (my bad). Bridging somewhat makes sense to me. Is pretty much putting two audio amps in parallel with a phase shift to effectively double the amplitude? I guess my other option would be to place a boost converter in ? But I don't have the space for that either. Like I mentioned LED's don't really matter at the moment because I am just trying for better audio quality. Also would wire length or type of connection have any effect? I stripped a 2 dollar set of headphones and soldered on a header for the left, right, and gnd input)

Comment: Ideally, to avoid the Q1 led issues, you should move that to its own op amp. A second op amp in parallel to the speaker amp.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing everything to the right of C9 in your diagram with this:
[image: Buffer Stages]
The FETs will act as *voltage* buffers, allowing your LEDs & your speaker to draw far more current than your opamp can source.

Comment: Thanks, Ill try that ! Does it matter what Q2 & Q3 are as long as they are npn?

Comment: Q2 should be an n-channel FET, _not_ an npn BJT. Q3 should be rated for >=8W & be installed as a voltage buffer(though you could use a BJT, FET, or opamp. see: http://www.circuitstoday.com/current-amplifier-and-buffers). At minimum, you want it to offer 1.5A to the speaker @5V signal (even though @ 4ohm, the spk only eats 1.2A @5V). The more current it's capable of "giving," beyond what the speaker needs, the better the "damping factor" & lower the distortion (until you clip @ 5v). Q1 needs to be a **PNP** BJT, or a **p-channel** FET, and be capable of running the 4 diodes in parallel.

Comment: Adding a series resistor to each LED would be a good idea, too (oops).